# How can I make two subnets visible to each other

Tags: wireless-networking, routing

I have a router that has an internal subnet range as follows: 192.168.0.x

The following devices are wired directly to the router:

- Windows PC
- Synology NAS
- Apple Mac mini
- Google Nest Wifi Mesh

All my household phones, laptops, tablets, and Epson WF3620 connect to the Google Nest Wifi mesh, which has a subnet of 192.168.86.x.

While the systems on 86.x can connect to the NAS, my wired systems on 0.x cannot see the printer. How can I configure routing on the Windows OS so that I can print from my network Printer?

My router only has four ethernet ports, so I am unable to connect the printer directly to the router.

Comment: Not an answer, but you could use a switch to expand the number of ports. £/$20 buys you an 8 port gigabit switch.

Comment: What is the make/model of the router ? Have to allow access between the subnets in the firewall settings if it supports that.

Comment: It is a virgin media Superhub 3.0 Model Number VMDG505

Comment: Cannot **see** the printer or cannot **connect** to the IP address of the printer if entered manually? Service announcement often happens via broadcasting in a single subnet. So if the service discovery is not working, you need to install something on your home router to forward service discovery protocols. Which home router firmware out of the box usually can't do.

Comment: the Windows PC on at 192.168.0.129 cannot ping (nor connect) the printer at 192.168.86.36. However the laptops and tablets (all on *.*.86.* can ping the NAS at 192.168.0.192